# Adding a value to Combo Box from the UI?

Tags: java, events, javafx, combobox, jcombobox

How can I make adding a value to items in a combo box possible so the user can either select from the existing items or clique "Add element" item to add a new item?

```
private ComboBox<String> comboStructDonnees;
```

Followed by:

```
comboData.getItems().addAll("TVW", "VWT", "TTVW", "VWXT", "Add item");
```

I don't know which event should I create next, I want to the text to be entered on the added element if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So do you mean you want the user to be able to add to the list of possible options or do you have two fields or do you want a editable combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an item with a "special value" (e.g. an empty string) to the end of the list of items for the combo box.

Use a cell factory to create a cell that displays a user-friendly message ("Add item..", for example) to the user when that value is displayed. Add an event filter to the cell that displays a dialog for inputting a new value if the cell is displaying the special value.

Here's a quick SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddItemToComboBox extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three", "");
        combo.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        if (item.isEmpty()) {
                            setText("Add item...");
                        } else {
                            setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, evt -> {
                if (cell.getItem().isEmpty() && ! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
                    dialog.setContentText("Enter item");
                    dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(text -> {
                        int index = combo.getItems().size()-1;
                        combo.getItems().add(index, text);
                        combo.getSelectionModel().select(index);
                    });
                    evt.consume();
                }
            });

            return cell ;
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(combo);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]